# Not able to change docusign signature when using sms Verification

Tags: java, docusignapi

When using the Sms Verification, the user can adopt a new signature if it s the first he is signing, but as soon the signature is adopted he can't change the signature anymore.
Is there something special to do to reanable this functionality when using the sms verification
Please find a video showing a test using the sms verification (signature change impossible) and one without (signature change possible).

Here is the signer code I used for the sms verification:

```
    final String signerName = getSignerNameClient( memberJson );
    final Signer signer1 = new Signer();
    final String signer1Email = memberJson.getLogin();
    signer1.setEmail( signer1Email );
    signer1.setName( signerName );
    signer1.setFullName( signerName );
    signer1.setClientUserId( signerName );
    signer1.setFirstName( memberJson.getFirstname() );
    signer1.setLastName( memberJson.getSurname() );
    signer1.recipientId( RECIPIENT_ID_CLIENT );
    if ( memberJson.getAdviser() != null && memberJson.getAdviser().getTelephone() != null && !"".equals( memberJson.getAdviser().getTelephone() ) && !"0000000000".equals( memberJson.getAdviser().getTelephone() ) ) {
        String phoneNumber = memberJson.getAdviser().getTelephone().replace( " ", "" );
        if ( !phoneNumber.startsWith( "00" ) && !phoneNumber.startsWith( "+" ) ) {
            phoneNumber = PREFIX_COUNTRY_PHONE + phoneNumber;
        }
        final List<String> RECIPIENT_PHONE_NUMBERS = Arrays.asList( phoneNumber );
        final RecipientSMSAuthentication smsAuth = new RecipientSMSAuthentication();
        smsAuth.setSenderProvidedNumbers( RECIPIENT_PHONE_NUMBERS );
        signer1.setSmsAuthentication( smsAuth );
        signer1.setIdCheckConfigurationName( "SMS Auth $" );
    }
```

https://www.loom.com/share/d46e1d8975e94dba90b67050a9a5c24f

Comment: Can you try another browser? just to isolate if this is a client issue?

Comment: Yes same issue , with Chrome, Brave and Firefox.

Comment: looks like a bug, you will want to work with our support engineers by going to support.docusign.com

Comment: Yeah I started with the support.After a week of back and forth they just asked me to do a enhancement request which I can't find any link. The support is pretty shocking. No reply on the GitHub repo either.

Comment: Sorry you didn't have a good experience, but this sounds like a bug not an enhancement request. You can also email feedback@docusign.com to send your feedback on the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I ll send them an email. Thanks for your help